# addeventlistener is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying add event listener to all a tags in the current document, so that when an a tag is clicked it stores the href value in the session. but the following script  I have written is not even alerting a value "sel".

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  window.onload=function(){
    var x=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
      x[i].addEventListener("click", nextlocation(), false);
    };
  };
  function nextlocation(){
     sessionStorage.setItem("next","sel");
     alert(sessionStorage.getItem("next"));
  };
  </script>
```

Comment: Should be `addEventListener("click", nextlocation, false)` without the `()`

Comment: `nextlocation()` is the result of the `nextlocation` function invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `nextLocation()` argument you are passing to `addEventListener` is actually invoking `nextLocation`, rather than referencing it, so the return value of the function is what is being supplied to `addEventListener` as the callback, but your function doesn't return anything, so the entire method call fails.

> So, correcting the problem is easy. Remove the `()` from the argument
>   so the function is referenced, but not invoked.

But, if you are going to use the DOM Event Standard for event wiring (`addEventListener`), which you should, then use it consistently. In other words, don't use `.onXyz()` event properties, as you did with `window.onload`, because they are not robust like `.addEventListener()` is.

Also, it is not necessary to add `type=text/javascript` to your `script` tag. In addition, `.addEventListener`'s third parameter, which specifies whether you want to use event capturing has a default value of `false`, so it's not necessary to explicitly pass `false` there.

So, a corrected version of your code looks like this:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var x=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
      x[i].addEventListener("click", nextlocation);
    };
  });

  function nextlocation(){
     sessionStorage.setItem("next","sel");
     alert(sessionStorage.getItem("next"));
  };
</script>
```

Comment: It's working perfectly and thanks for your great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the nextLocation function, not the return of that function, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  window.onload=function(){
    var x=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
      x[i].addEventListener("click", nextlocation, false); // HERE
    };
  };
  function nextlocation(){
     sessionStorage.setItem("next","sel");
     alert(sessionStorage.getItem("next"));
  };
  </script>
```

Comment: thanks bro for your help, Your answer is also correct.